# Pulling data from a closed workbook without opening it

Tags: excel, vba

The code to execute this problem is actually working but I'm having difficulties with the file explorer. When I execute the code the file explorer opens twice once at the intended point when the "mydata" line executes, but then again at the .Formula = mydata line and I don't know why.

Additionally it appears that the values put into the cells are the values from the workbook selected at the .Formula = mydata line of my code and not the mydata line of the code.

I've not tried much since I have no clue how to approach this issue. I was looking into commands that close file explorer.

```
Public Sub CreateCharts()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim SelectedFiles As Variant
Dim mydata As String

    SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)


        For i = LBound(SelectedFiles) To UBound(SelectedFiles)

            mydata = "='C:\Users\ME\Desktop\FOLDER\[SelectedFiles]CATS'!" & Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(11, 21)).Address

            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MASTER CHART").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(11, 21))

            .Formula = mydata 

            .Value2 = .Value2 

            End With

        Next i


End Sub
```

I want the file explorer to only open up once and actually implement the selected file path into the cells.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this without openig the workbook.

you can retrieve data with an connection in excel and get the data from a table on excel.

Use ADODB library

U can use adodb.connection and create a connection string in the excel!

Comment: Can you give an example in this context?